# I need to return the number of views a document was viewed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest, crawled-property

I saw about the ViewsLifeTime and ViewsRecent properties. The two return empty. How do I work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable Search and Query property for "ViewsLifeTime" and “ViewRecent”managed property via SharePoint Online admin center-> search->Mange Service schema. Wait for crawl content in SharePont Online.

Then use Search Query API to get the information.

Here is a post for [Retrieve Popular Documents Programmatically In SharePoint using JSOM and REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-popular-documents-using-jsom-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Properties are locked for editing, do you know if I can create a new one that does the same thing? Do you know the crawled property responsible for returning the number of views?